Posh-SSH Cmdlets Not Recognized for SFTP Upload to Azure Blob Container in PowerShell
I'm trying to upload a file from my local directory to an Azure Blob Container using SFTP with PowerShell on Windows 10. I decided to use the Posh-SSH module for this task. However, I'm running into an issue where PowerShell does not recognize the Posh-SSH cmdlets (Set-SFTPFile, Get-SFTPFile). Here's what I've tried so far:

Installed Posh-SSH using Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH -Scope CurrentUser -Force.
Imported Posh-SSH into my session with Import-Module Posh-SSH.
Attempted to upload a file to my Azure Blob Container via SFTP using the Set-SFTPFile cmdlet:
PowerShell
Code:
$SFTPSession = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName "<Azure_Blob_SFTP_Endpoint>" -Credential (Get-Credential) -AcceptKey
Set-SFTPFile -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionId -LocalFile "Filepath" -RemotePath "/container1"

However,I receivedd an error indicating that the term 'Set-SFTPFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
I confirmed that Posh-SSH is installed by checking Get-Module -ListAvailable Posh-SSH, which shows that the module is installed.


Why are the Posh-SSH cmdlets not recognized in my PowerShell session?
Is there a specific way to correctly import or use Posh-SSH cmdlets for SFTP file transfers?
Are any additional steps or configurations required for Posh-SSH to upload files to    Azure Blob Containers via SFTP?
Any guidance on how to resolve these issues or alternative approaches to uploading files to Azure Blob Storage via SFTP would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:

Windows 11
PowerShell version: 5.1 tried in 7 also
Posh-SSH version: 3.1.3

I would verify the cmdlets were actually imported. Try running a Get-Command -Module Posh-SSH to see if they indeed are part of the module as well

I tried, But it's not working.

Most likely it got installed for only one user instead of all Users.  PS uses the environmental variable PSModulePath to locate cmdlets.  Check by clicking start button and type Edit Environmental Variables for You Account.


Posh-SSH Cmdlets Not Recognized for SFTP Upload to Azure Blob Container in PowerShell.

The Get-SFTPFile cmd was replaced with get-sftpitem.
Instead of using the Get-SFTPFile cmdlet, you can try using Get-SFTPItem and Set-SFTPItem.
Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Import-Module Posh-SSH
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString “password” -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“user1”, $password)
$Test = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName " 10.80.1.81" -Credential $Credential -Verbose:($PSBoundParameters["Verbose"] -eq $true) -ErrorAction "Stop"
New-SFTPItem -SFTPSession $Test -Path "Path to file" -ItemType "File"
Set-SFTPItem -SFTPSession $Test -Destination "somedestination" -Path "somefile" -Force -Verbose:($PSBoundParameters["Verbose"] -eq $true) -ErrorAction "Stop"

Response:

Reference:  'Get-SFTPFile' does not exists in v3.0
Set-SFTPFile : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
